# recommend a Flash MP3 player supporting starting playing from a specific time

Tags: flash, mp3

I need a Flash player which can start my mp3 file from a specific time based on the embedding properties or on URL or just anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work
[Flash player with JS support](http://flash-mp3-player.net/players/js/preview/)

use method

```
method:setPosition
```

on event

```
onInit
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out JWplayer. it has a great JS api which you can use to move around the current position.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/